# Struts 2.5 ParameterAware and HttpParametersAware

Tags: java, struts2

We are using struts 2.3.xx after upgrade to struts 2.5.12 we found that the `ParameterAware`  is deprecated and we must use `HttpParametersAware`.

**Problem**

There is an action class which extends `ParameterAware` and **change** some parameters before action (It remove input masks for example removes `,` from `123,456,789`) :

```
public class Sample extends ActionSupport implements
        ModelDriven<SampleVO>,ParameterAware {


    @Override
    public void setParameters(Map<String, String[]> parameters) {
        for (String[] values : parameters.values()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                values[i] = Mask.removeMask(values[i]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

We tried to do this with new `HttpParametersAware` and some thing like:

```
 for (Entry<String, Parameter> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
             String key = entry.getKey();                
             Parameter newParam =  new Parameter.Request( key, entry.getValue().getValue().replaceAll(",", ""));

}
```

But I face the error

```
HttpParameters are immutable, you cannot put value directly!
```

Can we change parameters like we used to do it in struts 2.3.x. how ?! If not any alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done as

```
public void setParameters(HttpParameters parameters) {
         Map<String, Parameter> newParams = new HashMap<String,Parameter>();
         for(String key :parameters.keySet()){
             Parameter p = parameters.get(key);
             if(p instanceof Parameter.Request){
                 newParams.put(key, new Parameter.Request(key, new String[] {"new"+p.getValue()}));
             }
         }
         parameters.appendAll(newParams);
     }
```

complete credits to @YasserZamani

Please see https://lists.apache.org/list.html?user@struts.apache.org